# Easy way of counting precision, recall and F1-score in R

Tags: r, classification, auc, precision-recall

I am using an `rpart` classifier in R. The question is - I would want to test the trained classifier on a test data. This is fine - I can use the `predict.rpart` function.

But I also want to calculate precision, recall and F1 score.

My question is - do I have to write functions for those myself, or is there any function in R or any of CRAN libraries for that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [ROCR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html) library calculates all these and more (see also http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de):

```
library (ROCR);
...

y <- ... # logical array of positive / negative cases
predictions <- ... # array of predictions

pred <- prediction(predictions, y);

# Recall-Precision curve             
RP.perf <- performance(pred, "prec", "rec");

plot (RP.perf);

# ROC curve
ROC.perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr");
plot (ROC.perf);

# ROC area under the curve
auc.tmp <- performance(pred,"auc");
auc <- as.numeric(auc.tmp@y.values)

...
```

Comment: ... and for F1-score `performance(pred,"f")` gives a vector of F1-scores

Comment: and I guess that also the predictions must contain scores of confidence or probability for each prediction?

Comment: Just to clarify: `Performance` uses the `prediction` object that is constructed from the scores (`predictions`) and labels (`y`) of each case. There is no additional number beyond that (such as confidence, etc.).

Comment: @itamar Can you help me with computing area under precision recall curve. My question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508831/precision-recall-curve-computation-by-prroc-package-in-r) Thanks.

Comment: ROCR doesn't work if in the problem there are more than 2 classes to predict

Comment: @peschü seems to be right. `ROCR` expects the predictions to be confidence values, so that it can tweak the cutoff threshold and therefore calculate a ROC curve. However if you don't have confidence values because of the nature of your classifier, the outputs are very confusing. It's probably possible to extract the raw F1 score but it's not clear how.

Answer (score 30):

using the [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/other.html) package:

```
library(caret)

y <- ... # factor of positive / negative cases
predictions <- ... # factor of predictions

precision <- posPredValue(predictions, y, positive="1")
recall <- sensitivity(predictions, y, positive="1")

F1 <- (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

A generic function that works for binary and multi-class classification without using any package is:

```
f1_score <- function(predicted, expected, positive.class="1") {
    predicted <- factor(as.character(predicted), levels=unique(as.character(expected)))
    expected  <- as.factor(expected)
    cm = as.matrix(table(expected, predicted))

    precision <- diag(cm) / colSums(cm)
    recall <- diag(cm) / rowSums(cm)
    f1 <-  ifelse(precision + recall == 0, 0, 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall))

    #Assuming that F1 is zero when it's not possible compute it
    f1[is.na(f1)] <- 0

    #Binary F1 or Multi-class macro-averaged F1
    ifelse(nlevels(expected) == 2, f1[positive.class], mean(f1))
}
```

Some comments about the function:

- It's assumed that an F1 = NA is zero
- `positive.class` is used only in
  binary f1
- for multi-class problems, the macro-averaged F1 is computed
- If `predicted` and `expected` had different levels, `predicted` will receive the `expected` levels

Comment: hi thanks. I noticed that there is a warning when for instance one of the class never gets predicted. Do you think the calculation is still valid?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I made a little improvement to fix this problem. Now it's working right in such cases.

Answer (score 15):

Just to update this as I came across this thread now, the `confusionMatrix` function in `caret`computes all of these things for you automatically.

```
cm <- confusionMatrix(prediction, reference = test_set$label)

# extract F1 score for all classes
cm[["byClass"]][ , "F1"] #for multiclass classification problems
```

You can substitute any of the following for "F1" to extract the relevant values as well:

> "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Pos Pred Value", "Neg Pred Value", "Precision", "Recall", "F1",  "Prevalence", "Detection", "Rate", "Detection Prevalence", "Balanced Accuracy"

I think this behaves slightly differently when you're only doing a binary classifcation problem, but in both cases, all of these values are computed for you when you look inside the confusionMatrix object, under `$byClass`

Answer (score 7):

confusionMatrix() from caret package can be used along with a proper optional field "Positive" specifying which factor should be taken as positive factor.

```
confusionMatrix(predicted, Funded, mode = "prec_recall", positive="1")
```

This code will also give additional values such as F-statistic, Accuracy, etc.

Comment: or you can just (mode = "everything") to print all statistics.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the comment about F1 score being needed for binary classes.  I suspect that it usually is.  But a while ago I wrote this in which I was doing classification into several groups denoted by number.  This may be of use to you...

```
calcF1Scores=function(act,prd){
  #treats the vectors like classes
  #act and prd must be whole numbers
  df=data.frame(act=act,prd=prd);
  scores=list();
  for(i in seq(min(act),max(act))){
    tp=nrow(df[df$prd==i & df$act==i,]);        
    fp=nrow(df[df$prd==i & df$act!=i,]);
    fn=nrow(df[df$prd!=i & df$act==i,]);
    f1=(2*tp)/(2*tp+fp+fn)
    scores[[i]]=f1;
  }      
  print(scores)
  return(scores);
}

print(mean(unlist(calcF1Scores(c(1,1,3,4,5),c(1,2,3,4,5)))))
print(mean(unlist(calcF1Scores(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(1,2,3,4,5)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply get F1 value from caret's confusionMatrix function

```
result <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, Lable)

# View confusion matrix overall
result 

# F1 value
result$byClass[7]
```

Comment: It is not F1 value

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the  `confusionMatrix()` provided by `caret` package. The output includes,between others, Sensitivity (also known as recall) and Pos Pred Value(also known as precision). Then F1 can be easily computed, as stated above, as: 
`F1 <- (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)`

Answer (score 0):

library(caret)

result <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, label)

#This shows all the measures you need including precision, recall and F1

result$byClass